# Nginx serve Iframe from another port on the same IP address

Tags: nginx

I'm having some trouble serving content from another port in the IP address that hosts the nginx server.

Here is my. `sites-available` file

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/Cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/Cert.pem;
  root /var/www/EX;
  index default.html;
  server_name 123.45.678.91;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Im trying to show some information from a kibana instance like this

```
<div> 
    <iframe src="http://123.45.678.91:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/<INDEX>" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

But im getting a `Mixed content` error. It seems that the iframe is not being allowed because it comes form an `http` not `https` request.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Both services are being hosted at the same IP.

NOTE:
Also tried

```
src="//123.45.678.91:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/<INDEX>"
src="http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/<INDEX>"
src="/app/kibana#/dashboard/<INDEX>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browser does not allow insecure iframe content on secure site.
So there is two solution for this

1. you can use same IP and port for iframe content and differentiate iframe content using url path like below.

change your iframe url to **https**://123.45.678.91:**443**/app/**iframe/content**/kibana#/dashboard/INDEX
and simply add new location in nginx configuration like below.

```
location ~ /iframe/content {
    ...serve iframe content...
}
```

2. But if you want to serve iframe content from another port only then you can proxy_pass request to on that another port like below.

change your iframe url to **https**://123.45.678.91:**443**/app/**iframe/content**/kibana#/dashboard/INDEX
and add new location in nginx configuration which will proxy pass to different port number which is defined in different server block of same nginx configuration.

add below location configuration in secure port server block.

```
location ~ /iframe/content {
    proxy_pass http://123.45.678.91:5601/$request_uri
}
```

and create another server block in same configuration file like below.

```
server {
        listen 5601;
        server_name 123.45.678.91;

        location ~ /iframe/content {
            ...serve iframe content...
        }
}
```

So In this case browser will not be aware of content is being serve from another port so it will not complain.